# How to pass by argument to dplyr join function within a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I would like to pass an unquoted variable name `x` to a `left_join` function. The output I expect is the same as if I ran:

`left_join(mtcars, mtcars, by = c('mpg' = 'mpg'))`

I'm trying this:

```
 ff <- function(x) {
      x <- enquo(x)
      left_join(mtcars, mtcars, by = c(x = x))
    }
    ff(mpg)
```

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) :    'match' requires vector
>   arguments

Answer (score 8):

You need strings as input for `by` therefore you need to use `quo_name` break a `quosure` and return a string.

```
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

ff <- function(x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  left_join(mtcars, mtcars, by = quo_name(x))
}

head(ff(mpg))
#>    mpg cyl.x disp.x hp.x drat.x  wt.x qsec.x vs.x am.x gear.x carb.x cyl.y
#> 1 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 2 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 3 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 4 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 5 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#> 6 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#>   disp.y hp.y drat.y  wt.y qsec.y vs.y am.y gear.y carb.y
#> 1  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 2  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 3  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 4  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 5  108.0   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
#> 6  140.8   95   3.92 3.150  22.90    1    0      4      2
```

To use `x` for both LHS & RHS of `by`, we need to use `set_names`
Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450170/786542)

```
ff2 <- function(x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  by = set_names(quo_name(x), quo_name(x))
  left_join(mtcars, mtcars, by = by)
}

head(ff2(mpg))
#>    mpg cyl.x disp.x hp.x drat.x  wt.x qsec.x vs.x am.x gear.x carb.x cyl.y
#> 1 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 2 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 3 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 4 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 5 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#> 6 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#>   disp.y hp.y drat.y  wt.y qsec.y vs.y am.y gear.y carb.y
#> 1  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 2  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 3  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 4  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 5  108.0   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
#> 6  140.8   95   3.92 3.150  22.90    1    0      4      2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of passing a column into a function where the join happens with `"LHS" = "RHS"`  could look like this:

```
data("mtcars")

library(tidyverse)

function_left_join <- function(x) {

  mtcars %>% 
    left_join(mtcars, by = names(select(., {{x}})))

}

head(function_left_join(mpg))
#>    mpg cyl.x disp.x hp.x drat.x  wt.x qsec.x vs.x am.x gear.x carb.x cyl.y
#> 1 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 2 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4     6
#> 3 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 4 21.0     6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4     6
#> 5 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#> 6 22.8     4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1     4
#>   disp.y hp.y drat.y  wt.y qsec.y vs.y am.y gear.y carb.y
#> 1  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 2  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 3  160.0  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 4  160.0  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 5  108.0   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
#> 6  140.8   95   3.92 3.150  22.90    1    0      4      2
```

You can also potentially pass more columns to the `select()` function, in order join on multiple keys