# Joining on multiple variables within a function - R

Tags: r

I am working in R.

I have two data sets - data1 and data2.

```
data1 <- data.frame(region_name = c("North", "North", "West"),  
                    type = c("big", "small", "big"), 
                    gamma_rate=7:9)


data2<- data.frame(region_name = c("West", "West", "East"),  
                   type= c("small", "big", "big"), 
                   beta_rate=7:9)
```

Both of these data sets have columns called "region_name" and "type" in them.

I want to left_join data 2 onto data 1, by "region" and "type", **but within a function.**
If I was doing it without a function, this would be my output:

```
data_final <- data1 %>% 
  left_join(data2, by = c("region_name" = "region_name", "type" = "type"))
```

This my function:

```
my_function(group1, group2) {
  data_final <- data1 %>%
                left_join(data2, by = c({{group1}} = {{group1}}, {{group2}} = {{group2}}))
}

output <- my_function(region_name, type)
```

I know the bit in the "by...." argument is incorrect in the function. Can anyone help with out how to correct it?

This seems similar:
[join datasets using a quosure as the by argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449799/join-datasets-using-a-quosure-as-the-by-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But it looks like it is just for one join variable?

Comment: Please, provide an example data and how you would like to see your output.

Comment: Have added now - thanks

Comment: Any reason why you would expect it to be different for one joining variable vs multiple?

Answer (score 1):

If you truely want it as a function, I would pass your data in as well, then a function becomes universal and you can use it no matter how your two tables are called.

```
data1 <- data.frame(region_name = c("North", "North", "West"),  
                    type = c("big", "small", "big"), 
                    gamma_rate=7:9)


data2<- data.frame(region_name = c("West", "West", "East"),  
                   type= c("small", "big", "big"), 
                   beta_rate=7:9)


my_function <- function(join, df1, df2) {
  df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = join)
}

my_function(data1, data2, join = c("region_name", "type"))

  region_name  type gamma_rate beta_rate
1       North   big          7        NA
2       North small          8        NA
3        West   big          9         8
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
```

Dummy data

```
data1 <- data.table(region_name = c('a', 'b')
                    , type = 1:2
                    ); data1
region_name type
1:           a    1
2:           b    2

data2 <- data.table(region_name = c('b', 'c')
                    , type = 2:3
                    ); data2
region_name type
1:           b    2
2:           c    3
```

function

```
my_function <- function(x)
{
  return(data2[data1, on=(x)])
}
```

run function

```
my_function(c('region_name', 'type'))
region_name type
1:           a    1
2:           b    2
```

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data.frame(region = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                    type = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                    value = c(1, 2, 3))


data2 <- data.frame(region = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                    type = c("A", "D", "C"), 
                    value = c(4, 5, 6))

my_join_function <- function(group1, group2){
  data1 %>% 
    left_join(data2, 
              by = c(group1, group2))
  
} 

my_join_function('region', 'type')
```

| region | type | value.x | value.y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | 1 | 4 |
| B | B | 2 | NA |
| C | C | 3 | 6 |