# Using by argument programmatically in join functions dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I want to use the `by` argument of `left_join` function of `dplyr` package, passing objects with the string names which corresponds to column names of two different tables to by joined.

here is the code to build the two tables that I want to join:

```
library(tidyverse)
v1<-letters[1:3] %>% factor
v2<-letters[5:7] %>% factor
yname<-"W"

names_vars<-c("sex","st")

all_comb<-expand.grid(v1,v2)
colnames(all_comb)<-names_vars

f1<-paste0(names_vars,collapse = "*") %>% {paste0("~ ",.)} %>% formula

mat <- model.matrix(f1, all_comb)
int_terms<- colnames(mat)[-1] %>% str_subset(":")
terms<-setdiff(colnames(mat)[-1],int_terms)
subindx<-terms %>% str_remove_all(paste0(names_vars,collapse = "|"))

nterms<-data.frame(var=names_vars,
                   nterms=all_comb %>% apply(2,function(x)length(unique(x))-1))

terms_df<-data.frame(var=rep(nterms$var,nterms$nterms),terms=subindx,type="s")
terms_df$xs<-paste0("x_",1:nrow(terms_df))

int_terms_df<-int_terms %>% str_split_fixed(":",2) %>% data.frame()
colnames(int_terms_df)<-names_vars
int_terms_df<-int_terms_df %>% 
  apply(1:2,function(x)str_remove_all(x,paste0(names_vars,collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

(Sorry for the lengthy code to produce two tables). The two tables to be joined are `int_terms_df` and `terms_df`

```
int_terms_df
  sex st
1   b  f
2   c  f
3   b  g
4   c  g

terms_df[,c("terms","xs")]
  terms  xs
1     b x_1
2     c x_2
3     f x_3
4     g x_4
```

the join that I want to do is this:

```
left_join(int_terms_df,terms_df[,c("terms","xs")],by=c("sex"="terms")) %>% 
  left_join(terms_df[,c("terms","xs")],by=c("st"="terms")) %>% 
  mutate(xs=paste0(xs.x," ",xs.y),.keep ="unused")
```

Producing this table:

```
  sex st      xs
1   b  f x_1 x_3
2   c  f x_2 x_3
3   b  g x_1 x_4
4   c  g x_2 x_4
```

The problem is that this code will be the body of a function and I will need to operate over the `by` argument passing objects with the string name of the corresponding columns to the `left_join` function.

I have reviewed these resources ([r1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449799/join-datasets-using-a-quosure-as-the-by-argument/48450170#48450170),[r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings)) but the solutions provided are not working in my case, for example from [r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings):

```
xtemp<-"terms"
left_join(int_terms_df,terms_df[,c("terms","xs")],by=setNames(names_vars[1], xtemp))
```

produces the next error message:

```
Error in `left_join()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
✖ Problem with `terms`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I do note that examples presented in [r1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449799/join-datasets-using-a-quosure-as-the-by-argument/48450170#48450170) and [r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399065/dplyr-join-on-by-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-variables-containing-strings) are joins on the same data frame, in this case the tables to be joined are different data frames, I believe that this could be the source of failure for my intent to implement this in my case.

I appreciate any comments on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naming should be reversed in `setNames` i.e. whatever is the name of the variable, it should match the first dataset `by` variable

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(int_terms_df,terms_df[,c("terms","xs")],
      by=setNames(xtemp, names_vars[1]))
```

-output

```
 sex st  xs
1   b  f x_1
2   c  f x_2
3   b  g x_1
4   c  g x_2
```

It is also TRUE for `right_join`

```
> right_join(int_terms_df,terms_df[,c("terms","xs")],
       by=setNames(xtemp, names_vars[1]))
  sex   st  xs
1   b    f x_1
2   c    f x_2
3   b    g x_1
4   c    g x_2
5   f <NA> x_3
6   g <NA> x_4
```